# Calculating discount in paypal add to cart form

Tags: php, paypal

I'm new at using paypal add to cart form.i want to calculate discount for entire cart amount.

I even try `discount_rate_cart` and `discount_amount_cart` by referring this link.

[Link](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#id08A6HH0D0TA)

But, it doesn't working.

```
 <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
 <input type="hidden" name="business" value="example@gmail.com">
 <input type="hidden" name="business" value="sample@gmail.com">
 <input type="hidden" name="item_name" id="item_name" value="test">
 <input type="hidden" name="item_number"  value="1">
 <input type="hidden" name="amount" id="amount" value="24.99">
 <input type="hidden" name="discount_amount_cart" value="20.00">
 <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
```

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
shahana

Comment: *doesn't work* is not a valid issue description. Show us codes and expected result.

Comment: Could you post some code of what you actually tried?

Comment: This is my code that i tried.It doesn't show discount in add to cart form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks you all.I got a solution to my question.

If you are using discount in amount in add to cart form :

```
<input type="hidden" value=".50" name="discount_amount">
<input type="hidden" value=".50" name="discount_amount2">
```

If you are using discount in rate in add to cart form:

```
<input type="hidden" value="50" name="discount_rate">
<input type="hidden" value="50" name="discount_rate2">
```